# Problema con bucle for en Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, switch

Ciclo for solo se ejecuta una vez aún cuando debería ejecutarse un número determinado de veces dependiendo del dato tipo número que el usuario ingresa.

En este código se intenta replicar la compra de entradas al cine y el algoritmo funciona bien, salvo que cuando se llega al punto de escoger el tipo de combo y se ejecuta el ciclo for, se debería ejecutar tantas veces sea el número de entradas, es decir, si hay dos usuarios para ir al cine pues cada quien debería escoger el tipo de combo que desea mediante el ciclo for y no es posible ya que el mismo se ejecuta siempre una sola vez y no tantas veces como se desee escoger el combo de cada usuario. En este caso como parámetro del ciclo for está la variable i y dicha variable debería ser la misma que `cantidadEntradas` la cual se declara comenzando el código y justo antes de entrar al ciclo for se reasigna su valor para que represente el número de entradas que se desea adquirir.

```
let nombreUsuario;
let diaSeleccionado;
let cantidadEntradas;

const pelicula1 = "Thor: Amor y trueno";
const pelicula2 = "Minions 2: Nace un villano";
const pelicula3 = "Telefono negro";
const pelicula4 = "Top Gun: Maverick";
const pelicula5 = "Jurasic World: Dominio";
let peliculaSeleccionada;

const combo1 = "Pochoclos + gaseosa";
const combo2 = "Nachos + gaseosa";
const combo3 = "Golosinas surtidas + gaseosa";
let comboSeleccionado;

nombreUsuario = prompt ("Bienvenido a Cine-Online. \nPor favor ingrese su nombre para continuar");
console.log ("Nombre del comprador " + nombreUsuario)

do {
    diaSeleccionado = prompt ("Indique que dia desea asistir al cine");
    
    console.log ("Ha seleccionado el dia " + diaSeleccionado);

    peliculaSeleccionada = prompt ("Para el dia seleccionado las peliculas en cartelera son:\n1 - "+ pelicula1 + "\n2 - " + pelicula2 + "\n3 - " + pelicula3 + "\n4 - " + pelicula4 + "\n5 - " + pelicula5 + "\nPor favor ingrese el numero de la pelicula que desea ver");

        switch (peliculaSeleccionada) {
            case "1":
                console.log ("Ha elegido la pelicula " + pelicula1);
                break;
            case "2":
                console.log ("Ha elegido la pelicula " + pelicula2);
                break;
            case "3":
                console.log ("Ha elegido la pelicula " + pelicula3);
                break;
            case "4":
                console.log ("Ha elegido la pelicula " + pelicula4);
                break;
            case "5":
                console.log ("Ha elegido la pelicula " + pelicula5);
                break;                       
        }

    cantidadEntradas = parseInt ( prompt ("Cuantas entradas desea adquirir?") );
    
    console.log ("Requiere " + cantidadEntradas + " de entradas");
    
    for(let i=0; i < cantidadEntradas; i++);{
        comboSeleccionado = prompt ("Los combos disponibles son: \nCombo 1 - " + combo1 + "\nCombo 2 - " + combo2 + "\nCombo 3 - " + combo3 + "\nIngrese la palabra combo seguido del numero seleccionado");
            
        switch (comboSeleccionado) {
            case "combo1":
                console.log ("Su orden es " + combo1);
                break;
            case "combo2":
                console.log ("Su orden es " + combo2);
                break;
            case "combo3":
                console.log ("Su orden es " + combo3);
                break;                       
        }
        
    }

    deseaContinuar = prompt ("Desea realizar otra compra?");
}
while ( deseaContinuar !="no");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema seguramente es que se está mal definido el bucle,
la sintaxis correcta es :

```
    for ([expresion-inicial]; [condicion]; [expresion-final])sentencia
```

Por ejemplo:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
     n += i;
     mifuncion(n);
   }
```

En este caso el punto y coma separa la sentencia en dos y por eso no hace lo esperado:

```
  for(var i=0; i < cantidadEntradas; i++); <-- Un bloque 
  {....} <-- Otro bloque de código independiente
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes de la sentencia en el `for` pusiste un punto y coma, creo que ese es el error.

```
for(var i=0; i < cantidadEntradas; i++);{
```

Comment: Sí, ahí está el problema, la sentencia `for` está ejecutando "todo" hasta el punto y coma, lo que está en llaves al estar después del punto y coma queda fuera de la acción de `for`, por tanto es un bloque más de código y se ejecuta como cualquier otra pieza de código, una sola vez